# feenableexcept not producing core dumps

Tags: c, linux, floating-point, coredump

I can't seem to produce a core dump file from an intentionally added arithmetic error in my code, that is:

```
float x;

x = 0.0/0.0;
```

It seems to work when I created a small experimental program to test the floating point exception, but when I implemented it in the real application, it fails to produce the core dump.

Basicly, I am trying to produce a debuggable release version where I link in another file (debuggable.c) containing a function that uses GCC's constructor attribute to call `feenableexcept` which enables the fpe exceptions at pre-main initialisation.

**debuggable.c:**

```
void main_init(void) __attribute__((constructor));

void main_init(void)
{
    printf("Enabling arithmetic exceptions\n");
    feenableexcept(fegetexcept()|FE_DIVBYZERO|FE_INVALID|FE_OVERFLOW|FE_UNDERFLOW);
};
```

Then in the real application code, I added in the intentional arithmetic error to force a core dump but it does not seem to work. I have verified that `feenableexcept` is indeed being called and that it returns `0` to indicate success based on `printf` statements I added in. Furthermore, a core dump is produced if I use the `abort()` function.

It seems that I have configured Linux correctly to produce core dump files, but there is something about the way the application is written or ran that is not producing the core dumps.

I was wondering if I may get suggestions at what to check to fix this problem.

This is the version of Red Hat Linux I am using:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.4 (Tikanga)
5.4 RedHawk Linux (Lima)
```

Here is my GCC version:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
Copyright (C) 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Yes, I know its old but I am working with a legacy system.

**Update 1**

It seems that when I place the intentional arithmetic error in the `main()` function of the real app, it actually bombs and produces the core dump. It is not doing this in a callee function of the `main()` function unless you put the call to `feenableexcept()` in the callee function itself.

The constructor attribute technique seems to work without the need to make a call to `feenableexcept()` in the callee function when I tested it out in a simple application. I'm wondering what could cause it to do this in the real application?

**Update 2**

I called `fegetexcept()` in my real application at several places and found out it returns `0` immediately after the call to `setjmp()`. It seems that `setjmp()` is part of the C standard library and is used with `longjmp()` to perform "non-local jumps".

I'm not sure why it is resetting the exception flags to zero though. I initially thought that I should be using `sigsetjmp()/siglongjmp()` to preserve the signals and have adapted the application to do so but it did not helped either. Furthermore, I tested this out in my little proof-of-concept app and it did not reset the exception flags to zero after the call to `setjmp()/sigsetjmp()`. I'm stumped at why `setjmp()` is doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't seem to find the information to indicate why the exception flags are being reset to zero when `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` are called. It does not do this in my little proof-of-concept program.

A work around that I came up with was to use `feholdexcept()` to store the flags before the `setjmp()` call, and then call `fesetenv()` afterwards to restore the flags. This allowed the program to throw the exception and produce the core dumps as normal. I'm still curious as to why `setjmp()/longjmp()` is resetting the exception flags. If anyone knows please post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I did not test it, but I would assume this most likely doesn't work since gcc realizes your calculation is a constant expression at compile time and just assigns NaN to x which won't trigger an exception.

In other (IEEE) words: the constant is a *quiet NaN* as opposed to a *signaling NaN*

Comment: If this is the explanation, then the cleanest solution, if supported by GCC, is C99's `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on`. This should prevent the compile-time computation of `0.0 / 0.0`. Generally speaking, any code that may not be executed with the default FPU flags should be compiled with this pragma.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq: The `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS on` feature does not seem to be supported by my GCC version as it keeps indicating that it is being ignored. I also tried the `-frounding-math` with GCC as suggested by this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336786/floating-point-exceptions-gcc-bug) here and that did not help either.

Comment: to check if the above assumption is correct, you could try if you can trigger the exception with something that is not a constant expression, e.g. x = (double) rand()/0.0;

Comment: @mfro: I don't feel that is the case, because I tested the `x = 0.0/0.0` idea in my little program and it did throw the exception and produced a core dump.

Comment: in your tests, did you use the same optimization level than have for your real application?

Comment: I changed the optimization flag to 0 ie `-O0` for the debug version. The release version had it set to 2 ie `-O2`.